# Oracle time difference is greater than 5 mins

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I have two date column in one table Say date1 and date2,
I want to find the difference b/w these two column and result of the value, Want to compare with greater than 5 mins

Ex:

```
Select date1-date2 from XYZ   // Result of this something like +00 00:05:00.000000 
where date1 - date2 is greater than 5 mins
```

Above query is syntactically not correct, Written what I want to archive it

Can someone help me on this

Thanks
Pramod

Answer (score 1):

You said they are dates, but then

> Result of this something like +00 00:05:00.000000

which is an interval; which means the columns are timestamps, not dates. So, you can compare using an interval as well:

```
select date1 - date2
from XYZ
where date1 - date2 > interval '5' minute
```

[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=5606724f9f4e7877b1bbeea6a80a4b50)

Answer (score 0):

Difference of two `DATE` datatype values (and that's what you wrote) is number of **days** between them, so you'll have to "convert" it to minutes:

```
select (date1 - date2) * (24 * 60) number_of_minutes
from your_table
```

(`24 * 60` because hour has 60 minutes, and day has 24 hours).

Therefore, you'd check

```
select case when (date1 - date2) * (24 * 60) > 5 then 'More than 5 minutes'
            else 'Some other message'
       end as result
from your_table
```